# Set relation in Approximation theorem

Tags: measure-theory

In a part of demonstration of Approximation Theorem on Robert B Ash book, cames this set relation on a finite measure.

$\mu_n(A \Delta B_n) = \mu ((A \Delta B_n) \cap A_n)= \mu[A \Delta(B_n\cap A))\cap A_n]=\mu_n(A \Delta (B_n\cap A_n)).$
The Set function $\mu_n(B)$ is defined by $\mu(B \cap A_n)$.

Those two last equalities i didn't undertand why it is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the OP. The statement in Ash’s book *Probability and Measure Theory* is as follows:

> $\mu_n(A \Delta B_n) = \mu ((A \Delta B_n) \cap A_n)= \mu[(A \Delta(B_n\cap A_n))\cap A_n]=\mu_n(A \Delta (B_n\cap A_n)).$

**Proof.** By definition,
\begin{align*}
[A\Delta(B_n\cap A_n)]\cap A_n&=[(A\cap(B_n\cap A_n)^c)\cup(B_n\cap A_n\cap A^c)]\cap A_n\\&=[(A\cap(B_n^c\cup A_n^c))\cup(B_n\cap A_n\cap A^c)]\cap A_n\\&=[(A\cap B_n^c)\cup(A\cap A_n^c)\cup (B_n\cap A_n\cap A^c)]\cap A_n\\&=(A\cap B_n^c\cap A_n)\cup(A\cap A_n^c\cap A_n)\cup (B_n\cap A_n\cap A^c\cap A_n)\\&=(A\cap B_n^c\cap A_n)\cup (B_n\cap A_n\cap A^c)\\&=[(A\cap B_n^c)\cup(B_n\cap A^c)]\cap A_n\\&=(A\Delta B_n)\cap A_n.
\end{align*}
And the last equality is followed by definition of $\mu_n$.